# Not able to connect android app running on phone with localhost

Tags: php, android, xampp, google-cloud-messaging

I am making an Android Application using GCM. I am trying to register through my app running on phone, the inputs are not able to store on localhost XAMPP using php. My phone and laptop are running on the same network. There is some problem with the ip address of localhost. I am using this url for saving on local host, where 192.168.43.247 is the ip address when pc is running with the help of phone's 3G network. 
    192.168.43.247/gcm_server_php/register.php

Please help!

Comment: Then wich ip address do you use in your client? Are you using your phone as hotspot? Tethering?

Comment: Yes. I am using phone's network and with the help of phone I am creating wifi hotspot.

Answer (score 2):

`Open Xampp>apache>conf>http-conf` file in notepad.

Find Listen 80 and comment out using #(like #Listen 80) and write below it: Listen (static ip address of server):80

eg:

```
Listen 192.168.1.34:80
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your application on emulator with localhost database(Xampp) then you have to  use the IP address 10.0.2.2 instead of other local ip address .. if you want to use your aap on mobile then you you can use same ip .. press up arrow on left side if my answer is usefull for you

Comment: I am using this IP but still my app is having no connectivity with the local host.

Answer (score 0):

try to check by disabling firewall or use ipconfig /all command then get your ip from there and use this ip as server ip address.

If still facing error then it might be error of your local server the request may be block or something else that you need to find out.to check it try to open url in your android mobile browser.