# How to allow XAMPP Apache listening to multiple network ports?

Tags: php, apache, geoserver

I have xampp apache on my laptop. I have written an Android app and was able to run PHP script from the app using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466389/not-able-to-connect-android-app-running-on-phone-with-localhost)

Now I'd like apache to control request from different PORTs ; for instance right now, my Apache's (http-conf file) listens to 192.168.1.40:8011 for my PHP scripts (located in htdocs xampp folder).

I'd like Apache to also listen to another port on behalf of another server (Geoserver) lets say for instance 192.168.1.40:8012.

That way, it will direct my PHP request to xampp htdocs PHP scripts and direct my Geoserver WMS request to 192.168.1.40:8012/geoserver/Projet_NAME/wms

Could you help me do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this You want

https://serverfault.com/questions/28041/how-do-i-make-apache-web-server-listen-on-two-different-ports

If u find anything useful please abort it

Comment: Thank you Mishra and Happu Diwalli

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link

Link 1 [How to change XAMPP apache server port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port)

Link 2 http://www.complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/how-to-change-the-apache-port-in-xampp

Hope you can get some solutions from it

If you find it Helpul please abort it and if not just let me know

Comment: Hey. I knew about link 1 (I used it before). Actually what I need is to make Apache listen on 2 different port at the same time ...